# Wpf, How to drag object inside draggable element?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop, behavior

I am developing WPF application. I should implement designer page with draggable objects inside other draggable objects. Look at the picture:[image]

Now my **Drag and Drop 1 and 2** working, but when I am trying to drag **Inner object 1** and execute **Drag and Drop 3** it is not working properly. Instead of drag **Inner object 1**, I am dragging **Master object 1**.

My xaml code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MasterObjects}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Height}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid behaviors:DragBehavior.Drag="True">
            <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" Stroke="SlateGray" StrokeThickness="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InnerObjects}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width}" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Height}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid behaviors:DragBehavior.Drag="True">
                            <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" Stroke="SlateGray" StrokeThickness="1" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

And my DragBehavior class:

```
public class DragBehavior
{
    public readonly TranslateTransform Transform = new TranslateTransform();
    private Point _elementStartPosition2;
    private Point _mouseStartPosition2;
    private static DragBehavior _instance = new DragBehavior();
    public static DragBehavior Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
        set { _instance = value; }
    }

    public static bool GetDrag(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDragProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDrag(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsDragProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "Drag",
          typeof(bool), 
          typeof(DragBehavior),
          new PropertyMetadata(false, OnDragChanged));

    private static void OnDragChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // ignoring error checking
        var element = (UIElement)sender;
        var isDrag = (bool)(e.NewValue);

        Instance = new DragBehavior();
        ((UIElement)sender).RenderTransform = Instance.Transform;

        if (isDrag)
        {
            element.MouseLeftButtonDown += Instance.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
            element.MouseLeftButtonUp += Instance.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
            element.MouseMove += Instance.ElementOnMouseMove;
        }
        else
        {
            element.MouseLeftButtonDown -= Instance.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
            element.MouseLeftButtonUp -= Instance.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
            element.MouseMove -= Instance.ElementOnMouseMove;
        }
    }

    private void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        _mouseStartPosition2 = mouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(parent);
        ((UIElement)sender).CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        ((UIElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();
        _elementStartPosition2.X = Transform.X;
        _elementStartPosition2.Y = Transform.Y;
    }

    private void ElementOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        var mousePos = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(parent);
        var diff = (mousePos - _mouseStartPosition2);
        if (!((UIElement)sender).IsMouseCaptured) return;
        Transform.X = _elementStartPosition2.X + diff.X;
        Transform.Y = _elementStartPosition2.Y + diff.Y;
    }
}
```

I guess I should to fix DragBehaviour class, but I don't have any idea how. Now I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **MouseLeftButtonDown** event is [bubbling](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events) from the inner container to the parent one. Try setting the **e.Handled** property to true in your event handler. In this case, only the handler for the first clicked element will be raised and your code should work properly.

I also suggest that you use an [attached behavior](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17458) instead of a class with several attached properties. You can find it in a free [MVVM Framework](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExpress.Mvvm.Free) provided by DevExpress.
As a rule behaviors give you much more freedom in such scenarios.